# Find venue from Foursquare using data from Twitter

Tags: twitter, foursquare

Is there any way to find venue using Foursquare API having information from user status with geotag obtained by Twitter API?

From twitter status I've got all of the information [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/id/%3Aplace_id)  but I noticed that place_id is different than venue_id in Foursquare.

Right now the best way I can think of, to find place from tweet using Foursquare is to get from tweet: place.full_name and longitude and latitude and create a query using Foursquare API :

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll="latitude"," longitude"&query="place full name"&radius=10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this doesn't work without privileged access.  After re-authorising with my own test client, it is no longer populated.

It's part of the place data, but seemingly not for all clients e.g.

```
$ twitterapi '/1.1/geo/id/07d9e7d26f082002.json' | jq .vendor_info
{
  "foursquare": {
    "venue_id": "4ee8dbd9e5fadaeb5e3c7400"
  }
}
```

The example run on a Mac with homebrew and both "jq" and "yschimke/tap/oksocial" installed and authorized.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction, I was using tweepy and this value was always empty, even when I tried with your place id.

Comment: It potentially depends on your client permissions, I had an old one lying around using the iphone client.  After I re-authorising, I've now lost access to this data.

Comment: Does it mean that they changed something and the vendor_info is no longer available?

Comment: No, generally it means this data is only for the official apps.  I used to work there so I had some old credentials lying around.

There are leaked credentials around publicly, but that doesn't seem like a solid base to build on.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation.